# How to add a port to an OpenFlow bridge

Tags: networking, network-programming, openflow, openvswitch

I am currently using Open vSwitch to try to build a networking application. I had used mininet and was able to create basic topologies easily. I tried to replicate that without using mininet and I ran into problems configuring my switch.

When I attempt to add a port to my switch, it appears to add correctly to the Open vSwitch bridge, but does not show up with the OpenFlow controller. How do I correctly add a port to an OpenFlow switch using Open vSwitch? Here is what I have tried so far:

`$ sudo ifconfig lo:1 10.0.0.1
 $ sudo ovs-vsctl add-br switch
 $ sudo ovs-vsctl add-port switch lo:1
 $ sudo ovs-vsctl show
 7c625407-3eae-40d1-9dca-94307331790e
    Bridge switch
        Port switch
            Interface switch
                type: internal
        Port "lo:1"
            Interface "lo:1"
    ovs_version: "1.9.0"
 $ sudo ovs-ofctl show switch
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x1): dpid:0000566c1450f749
n_tables:255, n_buffers:256
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ...
actions: OUTPUT SET_VLAN_VID SET_VLAN_PCP STRIP_VLAN ...
 LOCAL(switch): addr:56:6c:14:50:f7:49
     config:     PORT_DOWN
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     speed: 100 Mbps now, 100 Mbps max
OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x3): frags=normal miss_send_len=0`

How can I add a port so that it shows up using the OpenFlow controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a port to the OpenFlow bridge I had to specify the OpenFlow port number of the port. I had to make a slight modification to the add-port command.

**Before:**

`$ sudo ovs-vsctl add-port <bridge> <port name>`

**After:**

Note: n is the OpenFlow port number of the port to be added

For versions of Open vSwitch <=1.9:

`$ sudo ovs-vsctl add-port <bridge> <port name> -- set Interface <port name> ofport=n`

For versions of Open vSwitch >1.9:

`$ sudo ovs-vsctl add-port <bridge> <port name> -- set Interface <port name> ofport_request=n`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the controller to your network. So just set it :

```
ovs-vsctl set-controller switch tcp:controller_address
```

You can read the ovs-vsctl manual for more information